# Prime which is not irreducible in non-commutative ring with unity without zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

> In a non-commutative ring with unity without zero divisors find a prime element which is not irreducible (if possible).

$p$ is *prime* iff $p|ab$ implies that $p|a$ or $p|b$, and $x$ is *irreducible* iff $x = ab$ implies that either $a$ or $b$ is a unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we deal with a commutative ring:

Let $p$ be a prime with $p=ab$. Then some $r$ exists with $a=rp\vee b=rp$. If $a=rp$ then we have $p=rpb$ leading to $p(1-rb)=0$ hence $1=rb$ showing that $b$ is a unit. Conclusion: $p$ is irreducible. Of course $b=rp$ leads to the same conclusion.

You could say that this doesn't have to work if the ring is not commutative because we also need $1=br$. Normally prime and irreducible elements are defined in commutative rings.

---

**addendum** concerning non-commutative ring (with thanks to @rschwieb).

$1=rb$ implies that $r(1-br)=0$ hence also $br=1$. Proved is now that $b$ is a unit.

Comment: What will counterexample in case of non-commutative ring with unity without zero divisor

Comment: I must admit that I have no idea. In your edited question you now speak of non-commutative ring. So after a short while I will delete this answer.

Comment: What if I remove condition 'no zero divisor' also. Motivation as mentioned in question.

Comment: It is not a good thing to add new questions to an old one. This especially if answers are allready given. You should just ask a new question and let it eventually be accompanied by a reference to this question. The edit of this question should be withdrawn in this context.

Comment: okay i'll do it